# how to select a text file from a directory and read it in GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a GUI system that should select a text file from a directory,open it and read it in a code.. I have this code for that( the part of getting the text file):

```
function FindCallback(source,eventdata)
     [FileName,PathName]= uigetfile('*.txt','browse')
 s={};
           fid = fopen('*.txt'); 
    tline = fgetl(fid); 
        while ischar(tline) 
           s=[s;tline]; 
           tline = fgetl(fid); 
        end
```

it shows me an error:

```
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.
Error in ==> GUI_oo>FindCallback at 77
    tline = fgetl(fid);
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

any advice..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be changed to

```
path = fullfile([FileName PathName])
fid = fopen(path);
```

Opening *.txt is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
fid = fopen('*.txt');
```

there is no filename "*.txt", the argument for fopen should be the real filename which you have stored in FileName above.

So this should be:

```
fid = fopen([PathName FileName]);
```

You might also want to check if FileName is 0 (IIRC) before the fopen because the user may cancel the file selection.  Try this:

```
if FileName == 0
   % maybe display a warning here
   return
end
```